# Merge two bitmap data

Tags: android, file, canvas, bitmap, android-bitmap

For my application, I have create two bitmap as per my requirements.

One for actual image that goes through some image processing and second logo bitmap that only display application logo on top left corner.

Now at saving time I want to combine these bitmaps and want to generate single JPEG file as output.

To accomplish this task I have write following code.

```
orignalbitmap = orignalbitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas savedCanvas = new Canvas(orignalbitmap);
savedCanvas.setBitmap(logoBitmap);
savedCanvas.drawBitmap(orignalbitmap, 0, 0, transPaint);
savedCanvas.drawBitmap(logoBitmap, 0, 0, transPaint);


try {
    orignalbitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/original.jpg")));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But at present I only got my original image as output not attached with logo. I want image with logo also that data available in logo bitmap. So how to combine both bitmaps data that I can't understand so please provide some guidance in this.

Answer (score 1):

use this function  for combine two bitmap in single bitmap

```
public static Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) 
{ 
    Bitmap cs = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
        width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
        height = c.getHeight(); 
    } else { 
        width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
        height = c.getHeight(); 
    } 

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f, null); 

    return cs; 
}
```

Comment: Here I want to overlap two images such as frame layout. I think now you got my point.